# How can I extract this JSON data under `data-amount` using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

How can I get the JSON data under `data-amount` using BeautifulSoup?

[image]

This is what I have tried:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/pricing/details/managed-disks/"
response = requests.get(url)
table_doc = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
data = []

table = table_doc.find_all(
    "table", attrs={"class": "data-table__table data-table__table--pricing"}
)[0]

table_body = table.find("tbody")
rows = table_body.find_all("tr")

for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all("td")
    res = row.find("span", attrs={"class": "price-data"})
    print(res)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the JSON data by accessing the `data-amount` *attribute* using `[<attribute-name>]`. In your example:

```
res = row.find('span', attrs={'class':'price-data'})["data-amount"]
```

Additionally, you can convert the JSON data (the variable `res`) to a dictionary (`dict`) where you can acess the `key`/`values` using the built-in `json` module:

```
import json
...

res = json.loads(row.find('span', attrs={'class':'price-data'})["data-amount"])
print(res)  #  `<class 'dict'>`
```